# How do I save a selection of points in a curve in blender 3.2?

Tags: selection-tools, vertex-groups, vertex-colors

Vertex group is not in the object data tab, vertex color is also not there. All the tutorials point that it should be there.

The points in a curve are vertices, correct? So, I should be able to save their selection. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Would you at least name one tutorial which points there? I've never seen a tutorial where they have vertex groups on a curve.

Comment: The  points on a curve are generally **not** vertices. They are Control Points, encoding parameters to a function by which an approximation of the curve can be _generated_ at a given sampling-rate / resolution. The (visible)  _approximation_ is made of vertices connected by edges.  The resolution can vary.. until it's set, you don't know where the vertices are going to be.  You can store named attributes on Control Points, accessible to shaders / other modifiers.. can you give a use-case?